# Javascript switch case falling through to default even with 'break'

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, switch-statement

I'm setting up a node.js discord bot that uses firebase to store a user's status. I have a switch statement set up to go through each command, and it's been working well so far. The default case is this:

```
default:
    message.reply("Unknown command type \"" + prefix + "help\" for a list of commands.")
```

However, after implementing firebase I'm running into a very unusual bug. Here's the code for checking another user's status with "!check"

```
case "check":
    firebase.database().ref('/users/' + msg.replace("!check ", "")).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        const status = snapshot.val().tagline;
        message.reply(message.author.username + "'s status is: " + status);
    });
    break; // <-- Break that isn't working
```

However, while the code works, the default case is also executed as seen below.[image: discord image]

I think this might have to do with the delay of retrieving the user's status from firebase. The fact that the default case came first is a good sign of this. Although I'm confused as to why the delay would cause the break to be ignored.

Comment: so what you are saying is that it is always going in default switch case?

Comment: @ManishKumawat All other cases function normally, it's only this case (The "check" case) that falls through to default.

Comment: what is the sequence of default and check? which is written first?

Comment: It's impossible to tell with what you have here.  My guess would be that your code with the unshown switch statement is being called twice.  Switch statements don't just fall through when you break.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat You were correct, the code that checks to make sure to not read the bot's own comments was failing. Thanks for helping find the fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the switch statement was being called twice. The code that returns if the bot is reading it's own messages failed.